# Convert Object to Pointer to Object?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, swig

I have the following in C++:

```
#ifndef INTERFACE_H
#define INTERFACE_H
class Interface {
public:
        virtual void blah() = 0;
};
#endif

#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H

#include "Interface.h"
#include <iostream>

class User {
public:
        void callBlah(Interface* ptr) {
                ptr->blah();
        }
};
#endif
```

And I have this SWIG interface file:

```
%module(directors="1") interface

%{
#include "Interface.h"
#include "User.h"
%}

%feature("director") Interface;
%include "Interface.h"
%include "User.h"
```

And I compiled:

```
$ swig -Wall -c++ -python -I/usr/include/python3.6m interface.i 
Interface.h:3: Warning 514: Director base class Interface has no virtual destructor.
$ g++ -shared -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m Foo.cpp interface_wrap.cxx -o _interface.so
```

Then, I ran:

```
import interface

class Implementation(interface.Interface):
    def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.__something = 1
    def blah(self):
            print("called python version")

i = Implementation().__disown__
u = interface.User()
u.callBlah(i)
```

And it gave:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    u.callBlah(i)
  File "/home/foo/test/swig/interface.py", line 142, in callBlah
    return _interface.User_callBlah(self, ptr)
TypeError: in method 'User_callBlah', argument 2 of type 'Interface *'
```

So the main issue is that the variable i is an object of Implementation (which implemented Interface) but User::callBlah() expects the parameter is a pointer to Interface.

My question is how to convert i into a pointer to Implementation/Interface without changing C++ code?

Thanks!

Comment: That should 'just work' and I can't see at a glance why it doesn't.

Comment: Turned out that replacing i = Implementation().__disown__ with i = Implementation() fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just by looking at this part of your code:

> ```
> #ifndef INTERFACE_H
> #define INTERFACE_H
> class Interface {
> public:
>         virtual void blah() = 0;
> };
> #endif
> ```

You have a class that has a pure virtual method. This means that you can not create
an object of type interface directly it will fail to compile if used. This means that you must inherit from this class and any and all classes that inherit from this class must implement the function `blah()`. Also since you are inheriting from a pure virtual abstract base class you should also have a `virtual destructor`.

You can do this:

```
#ifndef INTERFACE_H
#define INTERFACE_H

class Interface {
public:
    virtual ~Interface();
    virtual void blah() = 0;
};

#endif 

#ifndef INTERFACE_IMPL
#define INTERFACE_IMPL

class InterfaceImpl : public Interface {
public:
    InterfaceImpl() {}
    virtual ~InterfaceImpl(){}

    virtual void blah() override { /* implementation of blah here; */ }
};

#endif
```

Then what ever source code is using `Interface` directly replace it with either `InterfaceImpl` or with a pointer to an `Inteface` type. If you use the later you will have to do some casting between `base` and `child` class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Yes, I need to implement the interface.  However, I would like to implement in Python instead of C++, which I did -- Implementation class definition in my post.

Comment: @Hei Ah okay; I understand but I don't know Python as of yet... so my help is limited and stops there at C++ portion, but yes you need to fix the C++ compiler errors first. Oh and I made an edit to my post in the second class's definition for the function `blah` I added the `override` specifier. This is also useful when working with purely virtual classes, abstract classes and polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks for your help!